# Error-Branch IO : Trouble initializing Branch. Unable to reach the Branch servers, please try again shortly

Tags: android, deep-linking, branch.io, deeplink

I am trying to use Branch IO Android SDK, by referencing the [branch documentation](https://start.branch.io/#/integrate-sdk/steps) I created a simple blank application and implemented the  `onStart()` method in the Main Activity:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Branch branch = Branch.getInstance();

    branch.initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked before showing up
                Log.i("BranchConfigTest", "deep link data: " + referringParams.toString());
            } else {
                Log.e("MyApp", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);
}
```

After the application has been opened by the branch link, I received this error on the Android Logcat:

> E/MyApp: Trouble initializing Branch.  Unable to reach the Branch servers, please try again shortly.
>
> I/Adreno-EGL: : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1.C3__release_AU ()
>                                                  OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
>                                                  Build Date: 04/27/15 Mon
>                                                  Local Branch: mybranch9445032
>                                                  Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1.c3_1
>                                                  Local Patches: NONE
>                                                  Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING

Comment: Alex from Branch here: looks like you may have stumbled across some outdated integration instructions. Sorry about that! Could you give [these steps](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/android/) and let me know if you're still having trouble?

Comment: Hey Alex, it looks like the link you posted shows the same Android code that the OP has implemented.
I'm having the same problem, what part of the code is wrong?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the response. Ore is right, I can't see any different. Does the code should be located inside the Activity's onCreate()  method?

Comment: @orepor @YahavWinkler, looks like the code is correct (and *shouldn't* be inside `onCreate()`). We sometimes see this error if `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` isn't set in your **AndroidManifest.xml**. By chance, could that be the case? See [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Android-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK/blob/master/Branch-SDK-TestBed/AndroidManifest.xml#L11) for how it's set up in our demo app.

Comment: Thanks @AlexBauer.  You right, I didn't put the uses-permission tag at the right place inside the AndroidManifest.xml file. Now it is working properly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Fantastic! Let me add that as the answer, and I'll make sure we also put a mention of it in the official documentation

Answer (score 3):

Alex from Branch here: we usually see this error if your app doesn't have the `INTERNET` permission configured (see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) for more on the Android developer portal).

Try setting `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your **AndroidManifest.xml** and this error should clear up. See [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Android-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK/blob/master/Branch-SDK-TestBed/AndroidManifest.xml#L11) for how it's set up in our demo app.

Comment: I have same issue and I set the settings you explained with android.permission.INTERNET but I still have this issue

Comment: seems this is occurring from time to time despite internet permission is given. when branch support was contacted they say it's bad internet but I'm connected to a very fast internet

Comment: @astroanu Have you found any solution for "Internet error"?

Comment: @KetanPatel no sorry, our company switched to a different service, not because of this issue tho.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some troubleshooting tips related to the issue you're facing:

Ensure that your app has the INTERNET permission: Verify this in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Confirm that no ad blockers are active: Certain ad blockers may interfere with the Branch SDK. For example, in my case with a Redmi phone, the issue was resolved by disabling the private DNS.

Verify the correctness of your Branch key: Retrieve your Branch key from the Branch dashboard.